# Creating a combinational Primary Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, shared-primary-key

I am trying to create a very custom primary key, example in a `[table_1]` having columns `tble_id, date_entered, time_entered, card_number, name, address.`
I would like to have the primary key (tble_id) to be a combination of the columns: `date_entered, time_entered, card_number`. So for example primary key being: `2014082717010001`, in this case `20140827` being the date, `1701` being the time and `00001` being the card number.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make this id a string , separated by commas such as 20140827,1701,0001 therefore when you fetch each id , you can get each of the needed information by using $x=explode(',' , table_id) where you'll get $x[0]=date , $x[1]=time_entered and $x[1]=card_number but all of string type

Comment: ok but I have an exsisting table as well that I want to convert the current ID number into the format Given

Comment: let me get this straight, you want to insert these values in an existing table ?